# React Native performance for large amount of View in a screen

Tags: javascript, performance, react-native

I'm working on a `React-Native` project, For a reason, I should generate a large amount of `View` elements in a Screen. at last, I got what I want but I doubted it has a good performance. Assume my code is like below:

```
import React, { createElement } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const redOrBlack = num => num%2 ? '#f00' : '#000';

const rows = () => {
  const rows = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= HEIGHT; i += 1) {
    const row = createElement(
      View,
      {
        key: `row_${i}`,
        style: [styles.row, { backgroundColor: redOrBlack(i) }
      },
      null
    );
    rows.push(row);
  }
  return rows;
};

export default () => (
  <View style={styles.wrapper}>
    {rows()}
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'relative'
  },
  row: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 1
  }
});
```

The above code is a small scale of my project. A large amount of `View` element will build in screen. how I can understand its performance? please tell me about the performance of my code.